# Server Socket won't accept() local application handshake in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to connect a client application to my code through port 8000 on my pc offline. I am using the ServerSocket library to connect using the below code. The client's application sends XML messages across the port and I need to connect, interpret and respond. (Please bear in mind that I haven't coded interpret/respond yet when reading the below).

Every time I try to send a message from the client application (when running the debug feature in eclipse), the code gets to the serverSocket.accept() method which should be the 'handshake' between client and server and can't go any further. I am unable to change the client application obviously so need to figure out why it's not accepting the connection.

```
package connect;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class PortListener2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("> Start");

        int portNumber = 8000;
        try (
            ServerSocket serverSocket =
                new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Received: "+inputLine);
                out.println(inputLine);
                if (inputLine.equals("exit")){
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `telnet theserver 8000` from the client machine? Does it respond?

Comment: How do you know if the client is able to send a connect request to server? I mean waiting in accept() loop probably means there is no client to connect to.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. It will block on `accept()` because that's what `accept()` does; it waits for a client connection. I would say you have a network/firewall issue preventing the client from connecting if that's the case.

Comment: Or else you're listening on the wrong port. You need to close the accepted socket when you're finished with it.

Comment: I am listening to the correct port. I know that because i have the client application on my machine and I am controlling it. I am also closing the socket as far as I am aware, try (x) {} tries the {} block using x as a local variable and closes them after?

Brian I am trying your suggestion now, I have been thinking the same thing but disabling the firewall isn't working. I'm trying the program now on a virtual machine without a firewall (it's set up the as needed). Thanks for all the replies so far!